# How to set a property when calling an Aspect in VB.NET with PostSharp

Tags: vb.net, variables, postsharp, aop

Trying to set my property for my Aspect `made with postSharp librarry in VB .net. How can I do it?

Here is my Aspect:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class MyAspect
    Inherits OnMethodBoundaryAspect

    Public Property CurrentTool As String

    Public Overrides Sub OnEntry(ByVal eventArgs As PostSharp.Aspects.MethodExecutionArgs)
        MyBase.OnEntry(eventArgs)
        eventArgs.MethodExecutionTag = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnExit(ByVal eventArgs As PostSharp.Aspects.MethodExecutionArgs)
        MyBase.OnExit(eventArgs)
        Dim sw As Stopwatch = CType(eventArgs.MethodExecutionTag, Stopwatch)
        sw.Stop()

        Log.log("Method: " & eventArgs.Instance.GetType().Name & "." & eventArgs.Method.Name & " - Total time:" + CStr(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000), " seconds.")

    End Sub


End Class
```

How do I call it before my method to be able to specify my CurrentTool property? Because this code below doesn't work..

```
 <MyAspect(CurrentTool = "LOGIN")>
Private Sub CallTologInFeature()
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting an attribute's property value, you need to use `:=` operator.

```
<MyAspect(CurrentTool:="LOGIN")>
Private Sub CallTologInFeature()
...
End Sub
```